Why is my protobuf map field represented as RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer in the generated Python code?
I have a .proto file that defines a message with a map<string, string> field:
syntax = "proto3";

message Message {

  map<string, string> map = 1;
}

After generating the Python code using buf, the map field is represented as RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer instead of a ScalarMap. Here is the generated Python code for the message:
class ExchangeAuthzCodeRequest(google.protobuf.message.Message):
    ...

    @property
    def access_token_vars(self) -> google.protobuf.internal.containers.ScalarMap[str, str]:
        ...

When I print the type of the access_token_vars field, I get:
print(type(proto_msg.access_token_vars))
# Output: <class 'google.protobuf.internal.containers.RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer'>

My Questions:

Why is the map<string, string> field represented as RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer in the generated Python code and not as ScalarMap?
Is this the expected behavior, or am I missing something in my protobuf definition or usage?

Additional Information:

I'm using protobuf version 4.25.3

I'm using  mypy-protobuf version I'm using is 3.5.0

My buf configurations:


version: v1
plugins:
- name: python
  out: .
- name: mypy
  out: .
- name: grpclib_python
  out: .


Does it cause any errors?

Yes, when I am trying to convert the object to dict I get this error:
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence.
This contradicts the official documentation:
https://protobuf.dev/reference/python/python-generated/#map-fields
